# Chrome won't fire pdf submit button

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I have a pdf embedded in an iframe that has a submit button back to my webserver. Fires fine in IE. But Chrome (and probably other browsers) use their own pdf viewer that doesn't recognize the submit button.

Is there a way to make this work in chrome?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this.

Comment: If you link directly to the PDF rather than embed it in the iFrame and have Adobe Acrobat or Reader installed, you'll get a little pop up in the upper right of Chrome that will allow you to open the PDF in one of those desktop applications. As long as your submit URL is fully qualified, you'll be able to submit from there.